# How to check array null or empty in jsrender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-engine, jsrender, jsviews

This is My Code below

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   
  var test1 = {
    "type" : "success",
    "code" : "600",
    "data" : [ ]
   };
  
  var template = $.templates("#template");
  var htmlOutput = template.render(test1);
  $("#billListBox").html(htmlOutput);
  
  function billButtonOnClick(searchBillId,isComeFromBillClick,billDiv){
   console.log(searchBillId);
   console.log(isComeFromBillClick);
   console.log(billDiv);
  }

 </script>
```

```html
<div id="billListBox"></div>
```

I want to check data is empty or null in jsrender? how to check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `{{for data}}` then you don't actually need to test for empty/null (whether in code or by wrapping in `{{if}}...{{/if}}`).

You can simply write

```
{{for data}}
    ...
{{/for}}
```

and that will work fine even if it is empty or null - it will just render nothing for that block.

Or if you want you can use

```
{{for data}}
    ...
{{else}}
    output this if data is empty or null
{{/for}}
```

and it will output whatever you want for the null/empty case.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just check if `test1.data && test1.data.length > 0`

jsrender has if/else statements as well

Comment: for me this works {{if data }}{{if data.length != 0 }}<hr />{{/if}}{{/if}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var test1 = {
    "type" : "success",
    "code" : "600",
    "data" : [ ]
   };

//check condition if array is empty or not
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(test1.data)){
 alert("array is empty");
}else{
 alert("array is not empty");
}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```